# ng-class add depending on group date data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I have some data in an array name with **$scope.data** variable.

```
[
 {date:'02-05-2016'},
 {date:'02-05-2016'},
 {date:'04-05-2016'},
 {date:'04-05-2016'},
 {date:'05-05-2016'},
 {date:'05-05-2016'},
 ...
 ...
]
```

I have 2 css class (color1,color2). I want to add class in ng-repeat of each date group like

```
02-05-2016 => color1
04-05-2016 => color2
05-05-2016 => color1
...
...
```

I can't figure out how it will be in **ng-repeat**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have a mapping between dates and colors, it would be very simple.

Here is what you could do:

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [{
    date: '02-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '02-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '04-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '04-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '05-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '05-05-2016'
  }];


}
}]);
```

```css
.color1 {
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;
}
.color2 {
  background-color: #ababab;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="dateObj in dates">
      <div ng-class-odd="'color1'" ng-class-even="'color2'">
        {{dateObj.date}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your looking at grouping the dates with same color, here is what you could do.

Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.dates = [{
      date: '02-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '02-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '03-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '04-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '04-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '05-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '06-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '07-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '08-05-2016'
    }, {
      date: '09-05-2016'
    }];


    let currentColor = "color1";
    if ($scope.dates.length > 0) {
      $scope.dates[0].color = currentColor;
    }

    $scope.dates.reduce((prevObj, currentObj) => {
      if (prevObj.date !== currentObj.date) {
        currentColor = currentColor === 'color1' ? 'color2' : 'color1';
      }
      currentObj.color = currentColor;
      return currentObj;
    });

  }
]);
```

```css
.color1 {
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;
}
.color2 {
  background-color: #ababab;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="dateObj in dates track by $index">
      <div ng-class="dateObj.color">
        {{dateObj.date}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My dataset is variable length. Any number of object can be exist. Keeping in two different array and then mapping is not suitable for me.

Comment: I mean to ask, how do you know which color to assign for dates in your dataset?

Comment: The first date group will assign in color1 and the second date group will be assign in color2 and then color1 son on. The aim is one color class will not be repeat like color1,color1. This will be color1,color2,color1... ,according to group of color

Comment: Modified the code snippet as per your use case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback but this code is not working for this type of data set. `$scope.dates = [
    {date: '02-05-2016'}, 
    {date: '02-05-2016'},
    {date: '03-05-2016'},
    {date: '04-05-2016'},
    {date: '04-05-2016'}, 
    {date: '05-05-2016'}, 
    {date: '06-05-2016'}, 
    {date: '07-05-2016'}
  ]; `

Comment: It seems like an issue with the way $scope digest cycle throttling, with my earlier logic. Modified the code snippet now. verified with your latest data sample. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0Of9xaTQpojSuwxZ14zk?p=preview). At it's simplest, you could do this.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="{
  'color1':datum.date === '02-05-2016' || datum.date === '05-05-2016',
  'color2':datum.date === '04-05-2016'
  }"
  ng-repeat="datum in data">{{datum.date}}</li>
</ul>
```

If you wanted something more extensible, you chould use a function to check ([example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/U2R9UmQSzlEE4lYEQ4Gx?p=preview))

In your view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="check(datum.date)" ng-repeat="datum in data">{{datum.date}}</li>
</ul>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.check = function(date) {
  if (date === '02-05-2016' || date === '05-05-2016') return 'color1';
  return 'color2';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and different approach using `ng-style` just create an object

```
$scope.colors = {
    "02-05-2016": "{'background-color':'blue'}",
    "04-05-2016": "{'background-color':'red'}",
    "05-05-2016": "{'background-color':'green'}"
  };
```

and access the colors in `ng-style`

**UPDATE**

Using `ng-class` as you want to apply color 1 , color 2 color 1 ....so on to achieve this you can do like below.Here the `$even and $odd` are from `ng-repeat`

```
<p ng-class="{'color1':$odd , 'color2':$even}">{{x.date}}</p>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    date: '02-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '02-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '04-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '04-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '05-05-2016'
  }, {
    date: '05-05-2016'
  }, ];

  $scope.colors = {
    "02-05-2016": "{'background-color':'blue'}",
    "04-05-2016": "{'background-color':'red'}",
    "05-05-2016": "{'background-color':'green'}"
  };
});
```

```css
.color1 {
  background-color:red;
 
}
.color2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <div ng-repeat="x in data track by $index">

    <!--<p ng-style="{{colors[x.date]}}">{{x.date}}</p> -->
    
    <p ng-class="{'color1':$odd , 'color2':$even}">{{x.date}}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: My dataset is not finite.

Comment: @Akashkhan updated the answer try it out by running snippet